# mysql inner join with 3 tables issue with order count

Tags: mysql

I have the following sample tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_customer` (
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_email` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;

INSERT INTO `my_customer` (`customer_id`, `customer_email`) VALUES
(4, 'muthu.d@test.in'),
(5, 'nsrirengan@test.in'),
(6, 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(8, 'vinothini.k111@test.in'),
(63, 'sri.n321@test.in'),
(56, 'vesri.n@test.in'),
(57, 'veesri.n@test.in'),
(58, 'veeisri.n@test.in'),
(59, 'ren@test.in'),
(60, 'ren1@test.in'),
(61, 'nsrirengan123@test.in'),
(62, 'nsrirengan321@test.in'),
(53, 'sri.n@test.in'),
(54, 'royalrenga@test.in'),
(55, 'vesri@test.in');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_order` (
  `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ordergenerateid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `restaurant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usertype` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `customeremail` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=152 ;


INSERT INTO `my_order` (`orderid`, `ordergenerateid`, `restaurant_id`, `customer_id`, `usertype`, `customeremail`) VALUES
(1, 'ORD0001', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(2, 'ORD0002', 1, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(3, 'ORD0003', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(4, 'ORD0004', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(5, 'ORD0005', 3, 0, 'G', 'vinothini.k5555555@test.in'),
(6, 'ORD0006', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(7, 'ORD0007', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(8, 'ORD0008', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(9, 'ORD0009', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(10, 'ORD0010', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(11, 'ORD0011', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(12, 'ORD0012', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(13, 'ORD0013', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(14, 'ORD0014', 3, 6, 'C', 'vinothini.k@test.in'),
(15, 'ORD0015', 2, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(16, 'ORD0016', 2, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(17, 'ORD0017', 2, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(18, 'ORD0018', 2, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(19, 'ORD0019', 2, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(20, 'ORD0020', 8, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(21, 'ORD0021', 5, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(22, 'ORD0022', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(23, 'ORD0023', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(24, 'ORD0024', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(25, 'ORD0025', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(26, 'ORD0026', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(27, 'ORD0027', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(28, 'ORD0028', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(29, 'ORD0029', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(30, 'ORD0030', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(31, 'ORD0031', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(32, 'ORD0032', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(33, 'ORD0033', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(34, 'ORD0034', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(35, 'ORD0035', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(36, 'ORD0036', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(37, 'ORD0037', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(38, 'ORD0038', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(39, 'ORD0039', 19, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(40, 'ORD0040', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(41, 'ORD0041', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(42, 'ORD0042', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(43, 'ORD0043', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(44, 'ORD0044', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(45, 'ORD0045', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(46, 'ORD0046', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(47, 'ORD0047', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(48, 'ORD0048', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(49, 'ORD0049', 19, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(51, 'ORD0051', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(52, 'ORD0052', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(53, 'ORD0053', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(54, 'ORD0054', 13, 10, 'G', 'sri.nas@test.in'),
(55, 'ORD0055', 13, 11, 'G', 'sri.nasqw@test.in'),
(56, 'ORD0056', 13, 12, 'G', 'sri.nqw@test.in'),
(57, 'ORD0057', 13, 13, 'G', 'sri.nas1123@test.in'),
(58, 'ORD0058', 13, 14, 'G', 'sri.nqw13@test.in'),
(59, 'ORD0059', 13, 15, 'G', 'sri.nas123@test.in'),
(60, 'ORD0060', 13, 16, 'G', 'sri.nas12345@test.in'),
(61, 'ORD0061', 13, 17, 'G', 'sri.nqw123@test.in'),
(62, 'ORD0062', 13, 18, 'G', 'sri.nas123111@test.in'),
(63, 'ORD0063', 13, 19, 'G', 'sri@test.in'),
(64, 'ORD0064', 13, 20, 'G', 'sri.nas111@test.in'),
(65, 'ORD0065', 13, 21, 'G', 'sri.nas12354klk@test.in'),
(66, 'ORD0066', 13, 22, 'G', 'sri.nas123879@test.in'),
(67, 'ORD0067', 13, 23, 'G', 'sri.nasasd@test.in'),
(68, 'ORD0068', 13, 24, 'G', 'sri.nasqwe@test.in'),
(69, 'ORD0069', 13, 25, 'G', 'sri.nas121212@test.in'),
(70, 'ORD0070', 13, 26, 'G', 'sri.nasqwqw@test.in'),
(71, 'ORD0071', 13, 27, 'G', 'sri.nqw321@test.in'),
(72, 'ORD0072', 13, 28, 'G', 'sri.nas123123@test.in'),
(73, 'ORD0073', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(74, 'ORD0074', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(75, 'ORD0075', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(76, 'ORD0076', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(77, 'ORD0077', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(78, 'ORD0078', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(79, 'ORD0079', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(121, 'ORD0121', 13, 52, 'G', 'sssri.n123123@test.in'),
(122, 'ORD0122', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(123, 'ORD0123', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(84, 'ORD0084', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(86, 'ORD0086', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(87, 'ORD0087', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(89, 'ORD0089', 13, 31, 'G', 'royalrenga@test.in'),
(90, 'ORD0090', 13, 32, 'G', 'nsri.n@test.in'),
(91, 'ORD0091', 13, 33, 'G', 'nnsri.n@test.in'),
(92, 'ORD0092', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(93, 'ORD0093', 13, 34, 'G', 'sssri.n@test.in'),
(94, 'ORD0094', 13, 35, 'G', 'qwsri.n@test.in'),
(95, 'ORD0095', 13, 36, 'G', 'snsri.n@test.in'),
(96, 'ORD0096', 13, 37, 'G', 'ncnsri.n@test.in'),
(97, 'ORD0097', 13, 38, 'G', 'nwnsri.n@test.in'),
(98, 'ORD0098', 13, 39, 'G', 'ncnasri.n@test.in'),
(99, 'ORD0099', 13, 40, 'G', 'ncnsasri.n@test.in'),
(100, 'ORD0100', 13, 41, 'G', 'ncqqnasri.n@test.in'),
(101, 'ORD0101', 13, 42, 'G', 'asdqazsri.nas123@test.in'),
(102, 'ORD0102', 13, 43, 'G', 'nacqqnasri.n@test.in'),
(103, 'ORD0103', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(104, 'ORD0104', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(105, 'ORD0105', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(106, 'ORD0106', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(107, 'ORD0107', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(108, 'ORD0108', 13, 0, 'G', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(109, 'ORD0109', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(110, 'ORD0110', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(111, 'ORD0111', 13, 44, 'G', 'qsw@test.in'),
(112, 'ORD0112', 13, 45, 'G', 'asdasd@test.in'),
(113, 'ORD0113', 13, 46, 'G', 'qweee@test.in'),
(114, 'ORD0114', 13, 47, 'G', 'qweqwe@test.in'),
(115, 'ORD0115', 13, 48, 'G', 'nsv123sri.n@test.in'),
(116, 'ORD0116', 13, 49, 'G', 'asdasdasd@test.in'),
(117, 'ORD0117', 13, 50, 'G', 'asdasdasdasd@test.in'),
(118, 'ORD0118', 13, 51, 'G', 'qwerew@test.in'),
(119, 'ORD0119', 13, 7, 'C', 'kvinocse86@test.in'),
(120, 'ORD0120', 13, 3, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(124, 'ORD0124', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(125, 'ORD0125', 13, 0, 'G', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(126, 'ORD0126', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(127, 'ORD0127', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(128, 'ORD0128', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(129, 'ORD0129', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(130, 'ORD0130', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(131, 'ORD0131', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(132, 'ORD0132', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(133, 'ORD0133', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(134, 'ORD0134', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(135, 'ORD0135', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(136, 'ORD0136', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(137, 'ORD0137', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(138, 'ORD0138', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(139, 'ORD0139', 13, 0, 'G', 'sri.n321@test.in'),
(140, 'ORD0140', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n123@test.in'),
(141, 'ORD0141', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(142, 'ORD0142', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(143, 'ORD0143', 13, 55, 'G', 'vesri@test.in'),
(144, 'ORD0144', 13, 56, 'G', 'vesri.n@test.in'),
(145, 'ORD0145', 13, 57, 'G', 'veesri.n@test.in'),
(146, 'ORD0146', 13, 58, 'G', 'veeisri.n@test.in'),
(147, 'ORD0147', 13, 59, 'G', 'ren@test.in'),
(148, 'ORD0148', 13, 60, 'G', 'ren1@test.in'),
(149, 'ORD0149', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(150, 'ORD0150', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in'),
(151, 'ORD0151', 13, 53, 'C', 'sri.n@test.in');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_restaurant` (
  `restaurant_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `restaurant_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`restaurant_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;

INSERT INTO `my_restaurant` (`restaurant_id`, `restaurant_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Fuji Sushi'),
(2, 'Big Pete''s Pizza'),
(3, 'Vinos Pizza'),
(4, 'Wafaa and Mikes Cafe'),
(5, 'Fuji Sushi (San Marco Blvd)'),
(6, 'Midtown Deli + Cafe'),
(7, 'De Real Ting Cafe'),
(8, 'Alex Delicatessen'),
(9, 'Two Doors Down Restaurant'),
(10, 'Ginas Deli'),
(11, 'The Mudville Grille (Beach Blvd)'),
(12, 'Casbah Cafe'),
(13, 'Alexander Grill'),
(14, 'The Southern Grill'),
(15, 'Cool Moose Cafe'),
(16, 'Basil: Thai and Sushi'),
(17, 'Hot Wok'),
(18, 'China Joy'),
(19, 'Blu Diner'),
(21, 'New Test restaurant'),
(22, 'testing res');
```

I have written the following SQL for Most Order done by customer with restauant.

```
SELECT o.customeremail AS custemail, o.restaurant_id, rest.restaurant_name, COUNT( o.customeremail ) AS totalordercount
FROM my_order AS o
INNER JOIN my_customer AS cust ON cust.customer_email = o.customeremail
INNER JOIN my_restaurant AS rest ON rest.restaurant_id = o.restaurant_id
WHERE o.orderid IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY o.restaurant_id
ORDER BY totalordercount DESC
```

I'm getting the result like this.

```
custemail           restaurant_id   restaurant_name            totalordercount
sri.n@test.in       13              Alexander Grill            79
vinothini.k@test.in 3               Vinos Pizza                12
sri.n@test.in       2               Big Pete's Pizza            5
sri.n@test.in       19              Blu Diner                   2
vinothini.k@test.in 1               Fuji Sushi                  1
sri.n@test.in       8               Alex Delicatessen           1
sri.n@test.in       5               Fuji Sushi (San Marco Blvd) 1

SELECT * 
FROM  `my_order` 
WHERE  `restaurant_id` =13
AND  `customeremail` =  'sri.n@test.in'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I'm getting from above query with 71 rows only. But my query is showing the rows 79

```
sri.n@test.in       13              Alexander Grill            79
```

But I need the output like this.

```
custemail           restaurant_id   restaurant_name            totalordercount
sri.n@test.in       13              Alexander Grill            71
vinothini.k@test.in 3               Vinos Pizza                12
sri.n@test.in       2               Big Pete's Pizza            5
sri.n@test.in       19              Blu Diner                   2
vinothini.k@test.in 1               Fuji Sushi                  1
sri.n@test.in       8               Alex Delicatessen           1
sri.n@test.in       5               Fuji Sushi (San Marco Blvd) 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, you're misusing the [pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html) by trying to display a customer email in your result set aggregated by restaurant. Your misuse of this causes your result set to contain arbitrary values of custemail.

Second, this simple query reveals that there are 121 orders for the Alexander Grill. Your claim that there are only 71 seems to be incorrect.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), o.restaurant_id, r.restaurant_name
  FROM my_order AS o
  LEFT JOIN my_restaurant AS r ON o.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id
 GROUP BY o.restaurant_id, r.restaurant_name
```

Third, there are quite a few orders with a customer_id that isn't found in your customer table. You're using `INNER JOIN` so your query is dropping and not counting those orders. `LEFT JOIN` will restore those dropped records. But still, you are not using the results of that JOIN.

Fourth, your `WHERE o.orderid IS NOT NULL` clause is pointless: that column is a primary key.

Try this query leaving out the `my_customer` table JOIN:

```
SELECT o.restaurant_id, 
       rest.restaurant_name, 
       COUNT( DISTINCT o.customer_id ) AS distinctcustomercount,
       COUNT( * ) AS totalordercount
  FROM my_order AS o
  LEFT JOIN my_restaurant AS rest ON rest.restaurant_id = o.restaurant_id
 GROUP BY o.restaurant_id, rest.restaurant_name  /* fix GROUP BY misuse */
 ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC, rest.restaurant_name
```

I think this does the trick for you.  It fully specifies the `GROUP BY`, and it does some kind of ordering among the restaurant rows that only have one order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for visit count for restaurants for a customer email that has presence in the customer table. The other numbers just turn out to be right because the others from the 71'er have only visited one restaraunt.
You need to add the customer email to the group by if you want customers for each restaurant.

```
SELECT o.customeremail AS custemail, 
       o.restaurant_id, rest.restaurant_name, COUNT(o.customeremail ) AS totalordercount
FROM my_order AS o
INNER JOIN my_customer AS cust ON cust.customer_email = o.customeremail
INNER JOIN my_restaurant AS rest ON rest.restaurant_id = o.restaurant_id
GROUP BY o.restaurant_id, o.customeremail
ORDER BY totalordercount DESC
```

My answer is the same as Ollie's except I leave the customer join in, I think that presence is required to get the results expected.